# how to group by one column only using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I am using a Linq query to group a column (string of Phones) and return that column and the last value of a second column called Status (also a string of numbers). I want to add the result of this query to a new dataTable.

I've tried it in many ways, but the result is always a group of the two columns together and not by one only. If I remove the field status from the dataTable then the group works good, but I need it. Example:

### phone   status

123   ---------     1

123   ---------     2

I want to retrieve the result: 123, 2 but I get the two rows.
Any idea why something like that might happen? This is the code:

```
var queryGroupLog =
from log2 in lg2.AsEnumerable()
group log2 by log2.Field<string>("Phone") into groupPhone
select groupPhone.OrderBy(p => p.Field<string>("Status")).LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var queryGroupLog = from log2 in lg2.AsEnumerable()
                    group log2 by log2.Field<string>("Phone") into groupPhone
                    select new 
                    {
                        Phone = groupPhone.Key,
                        Status = groupPhone.OrderBy(p => p.Field<string>("Status"))
                                           .LastOrDefault()
                    };
```

Comment: is this equals `groupPhone.Max(...)`?

Comment: @Grundy I think it's the same. However, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I'm getting the same result. I'm the checking the result in two ways: 
1.
          foreach (var row in queryGroupLog)
          {
              log_grouped.Rows.Add(row);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", log_grouped.Rows.Count);
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.
            foreach (var nameGroup in queryGroupLog)
          {Console.WriteLine("{0}", b);
              b++;
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------I'm getting the number of a result of a group by both columns.

Comment: Found the problem! and used the answer above also. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
new KeyValuePair(groupPhone.Key,groupPhone.OrderBy((p) => p.Field("Status")).LastOrDefault()))
```